# How we can deploy Desktop application to clients, for Java 11?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Previously, this is how we deploy legacy desktop application (https://jstock.org, written in Swing and JavaFX) to clients.

- Developed in Swing and JavaFX
- Use NetBeans as IDE
- Use Java 8
- Use Oracle JDK
- Use Launch4J to create EXE
- Use NSIS to create installer, will help user automatically download JRE from http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=216434

---

Due to the complex licensing requirement introduced by Oracle, we want to move away from Oracle, and go for Amazon Corretto or AdoptOpenJDK or Azul or whatever is free.

We want to take this opportunity to migrate to Java 11. **But, we notice that there are no JRE for Java 11.**

After some research, we though we might need "Self-Contained Application Packaging" technology, to deploy our Desktop app solution to clients, if we were to use

- Developed in Swing and JavaFX
- Use NetBeans as IDE
- Use Java 11
- Use Amazon Corretto or AdoptOpenJDK or whatever is free

The information we came across is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1307236 . But, it is pretty brief, and we still don't know how we can apply "Self-Contained Application Packaging" for our case?

Do you come across any good tutorial resource, to deploy Java 11 desktop app?

Comment: There's the upcoming [`jpackage` (JEP 343)](https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) tool. However, I'm not sure how such JEPs apply to other Java distributions.